# Set country based on longitude and latitude - Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a BQ table with longitude and latitude location. For example: (37.8532261, -119.6911924).
I'm looking for a simple solution within BQ where I can join those locations to a countries table with a multi/polygon.
I found this table: `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.states` but it's only limited to US states.
Is there any public countries table in Bigquery?
Is there any other simple solution I can use without API call?

Thanks!